# reaching from $\hat{A}=A_{\alpha\beta}|\alpha\rangle\langle\beta|$ to $\hat{A}=A_{\alpha\beta}a_\alpha^\dagger a_\beta$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, many-body

In quantum mechanics we learn that an operator in a basis can be represented as $$\hat{A}=\sum\limits_{\alpha,\beta}A_{\alpha\beta}|\alpha\rangle\langle\beta|.$$ But in many-body physics we suddenly write $$\hat{A}=\sum\limits_{\alpha,\beta}A_{\alpha\beta}a_\alpha^\dagger a_\beta$$

Any idea how to reach to the second from the first. I got something this $$\hat{A}=\sum\limits_{\alpha,\beta}A_{\alpha\beta}|\alpha\rangle\langle\beta|=\sum\limits_{\alpha,\beta}A_{\alpha\beta}a_\alpha^\dagger|0\rangle\langle0| a_\beta$$ Any idea how to show this? Please help

Comment: These two are not related in such a simple way.  Why should they, anyways?

Comment: I thought I can arrive at the second from the first because that is how we represent operators in QM

Comment: For fermions and bosons, it is not clear a priori what $|\alpha\rangle$ is supposed to be.

Comment: "Quantum Theory of Many-Particle Systems" by Fetter and Walecka covers the transition from first quantization to second quantization in full details, in the first chapter. As for your example, it is a matter of how you label many-body states.

Answer (score 0):

You first equation contains an operator $\hat A$  acting in the single-particle Hilbert space ${\mathcal H}_1$. The second equation contains an operator $\hat A$ that  acts on the many particle Fock space. The two operators are *not* the same therefore, although they are related in that the second is induced in a natural way from the first..

A Fock space is  built built by taking sums of tensor-products of copies of the   single-particle space: 
$$
{\mathcal H}_{\rm Fock}= \sum_{N=0}^\infty \{{\mathcal H}_1\}^{\otimes N},
$$ 
where
$$
\{{\mathcal H}_1\}^{\otimes N}={\mathcal H}_1\otimes {\mathcal H}_1\otimes \ldots {\mathcal H}_1,\quad \hbox{N factors}.
$$
The tensor product should be symmetrised or antsymmetrised for Bosons or Fermions, respectively.  If this sounds mysterious, the suggestion by IamAStudent is a good one.